# C# interface inheritance

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, interface

Given:

```
public interface IA
{
    void TestMethod();
}

public interface IB : IA
{
}
```

Why:

```
typeof(IB).GetMethods().Count() == 0;
```

?

Just to be clear:

```
public class A
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
}

typeof(B).GetMethods().Count();
```

does work (it returns 5);

As a bonus:

```
typeof(IB).BaseType == null
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is the code for getting the counts for both IA and IB:

```
var ibCount = typeof(IB).GetMethods().Count(); // returns 0
var iaCount = typeof (IB).GetInterfaces()[0].GetMethods().Count(); // return 1
```

Note that in production code I wouldn't use `GetInterfaces()[0]` as typically in the code where I would use this I can't assume that I will always have at least one interface.

I also tried out the bindingflags as follows:

```
const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
var ibCount = typeof(IB).GetMethods(bindingFlags).Count();
```

However, this will still return 0 as interface `IB` still doesn't implement method `TestMethod()`. Interface `IA` does. Using binding flags would work if both `IA` and `IB` were classes. In that case however, you get a return value of 5. Don't forget that IA implicitly derives from class `Object`!

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I know I can iterate over interfaces and get methods from them.
My question was why can't I do it that way.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be the design of the GetMethods function.  It doesn't support inherited members in interfaces.  If you want to discover all the methods, you need to query each interface type directly.

Check out the community content section of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(VS.90).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Consider IA to be an interface of IB, not its base.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define some Bindingflags into GetMethods().

Try

```
typeof(IB).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Count();
```

Comment: I've ommited BindingFlags because they are not helping ;).

Comment: Binding flags don't help in this case. They help when classes are involved.